# Unable to understand the independence of events.

Tags: probability

So here is the question:

> One card is drawn at random from a well-shuffled deck of $52$ cards. In how many of the following cases are the events $E$ and $F$ independent?
>
> (i) $E$: 'the card drawn is a spade', $F$: 'the card is drawn is an ace'
>
> (ii) $E$: 'the card drawn is black', $F$: 'the card drawn is a king'
>
> (iii) $E$: 'the card drawn is a king or queen', $F$: 'the card drawn is a queen or jack'.

I know the $\mathbb{P}(E \cap F) = \mathbb{P}(E)\mathbb{P}(F)$ rule and can solve the question using this rule. (The answer is (i) and (ii)).

But I still can't get a proper understanding of the question, if I pick a random card and it happens to be an ace of spades, it should change the probability of picking an ace next.

Unless we replace the cards after picking them, but in that case the (iii) should also be independent right?

I'm probably making a stupid mistake or oversight.

Please go hard on me.

Comment: Note that the question does not talk about a second card. In each scenario, a single card is drawn, and $E$ and $F$ pertain to that card. Does that help clear your confusion?

Comment: The question says, **one** card is drawn, so the question of "picking an ace next" doesn't arise.

Comment: Then shouldn't the 3rd case also be independent?

Comment: @Haris They aren't tho. The given answer is (i) and (ii) and using P(E ∩ F) = P(E)*P(F) also shows the same

Comment: @PhantomSucksAtPhysics please read my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the question is talking about two events happening with respect to the same draw.

For example, we draw a card. Event $E$ is is the card being a spade and event $F$ is the card being an ace.

If this understanding is correct, then this is an example of independent events. The knowledge of the event $E$ happening or not does not affect the probability of event $F$ happening, at all.

Here's an intuitive (hopefully) explanation of why. The proportion of aces is the same in spades ($1/13$) as that in non-spades ($3/39$). So it doesn't matter whether the drawn card is a spade or not. The probability of it being an ace remains the same.

So (i) and (ii) are examples of independent events.

On the other hand, the third pair of events are different. If event $E$ has happened, the probability of event $F$ happening is different compared to if $E^c$ has happened.

Think about it. If $E$ has happened, it means the card is a king or a queen. So it can be any of the $8$ cards that are K or Q. so the probability of it being a queen or jack (event $F$) is $4/8 = 1/2$.

But if $E^c$ has happened, the card has to be one of the $44$ cards that are not K/Q. And so the probability of it being a Q/J is $4/44 = 1/11$.

Clearly, in this case $F$ is NOT independent of $E$.

So for (iii), we have dependent events.

---

> ...if I pick a random card and it happens to be an ace of spades, it
> should change the probability of picking an ace next.

We are not drawing two cards in succession. So there's no "next" here.

Comment: B- But why are the third pair of events different from the first two?

Comment: @PhantomSucksAtPhysics edited the answer to explain why

Comment: The intuition here is good, but your last sentence doesn't make sense - $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ is the definition of independence, so it certainly does arise.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Made the correction. And thanks., i learned something.

Comment: ah thanks for you answer, i certainly have a better idea of this now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to pick a uniformly random card. Pick a suit uniformly from $\{\spadesuit,\heartsuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit\}$. Pick a rank uniformly from $\{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K\}$. Now choose the card of that rank and that suit.

This works, because every rank-suit combination is a real card, and there are no other cards.

Now in (i) and (ii) $E$ refers only to the first choice, and $F$ to the second. That is why they must be independent.

However, in (iii) both events refer to the second choice, so there is no reason to expect them to be independent (and in fact they are not).

(The fact that they both refer to one of the two choices doesn't *prove* that they are dependent - after all, there may be a way to break that choice up into two subchoices. For example, the events "red card" and "$\spadesuit$ or $\heartsuit$" are independent.)

Comment: This makes things much clearer, it seems my basic understanding of independent events is a bit janky. Thanks for your time!